# Suddently, "R.java" was deleted from my "CheckBox" program?

Tags: android, checkbox, r.java-file

I'm learning Android (I'm a beginner) and making a program for `CheckBox`.
Everything seems fine, but when I cleaned my project suddenly, R.java was deleted and it's giving an error.
I checked three times, but not getting it back.

Here is my source code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="IPhone" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android" 
        android:checked="true"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Windows Mobile"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Display" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.lesson06;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnChkbox();
    }
    public void addListenerOnChkbox(){
        CheckBox chkbx=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        chkbx.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bro..try Android :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton(){
        final CheckBox chkbx=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        final CheckBox chkbx2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        final CheckBox chkbx3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        final Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
                result.append("IPhone check: ").append(chkbx.isChecked());
                result.append("\nAndroid check: ").append(chkbx2.isChecked());
                result.append("\nWindows Mobile Check: ").append(chkbx3.isChecked());

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: oops sorry, i edited my button tag still not getting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Button Tag not closed into `activity_main.xml`

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Display"
```

Close that

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Display" />
```

and clean project. Your `R.java` class will be generated.

Comment: oops sorry, i edited my button tag still not getting!!

Comment: @developerknownasInsane Did you cleaned the project? Go to error window and see if any error present inside xml.

Comment: @developerknownasInsane Be sure that your project has no errors in the XML files, check them one by one.

Comment: By the way it's a great massive problem with Eclipse, What IDE do you prefer for developing Android?

Comment: :) Android Studio I used to use.  But eclipse is also a good IDE. Sometime this doesn't clears the project (basically rebuilds the project), so u need to restart eclipse. By the way you can use Android Studio.

Comment: really, i'm a beginner, can i use? ..i have always problem with Eclipse, i mean firstly clean=> save => and then blah! blah!...

Comment: :) No worry. Use Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Change your button to the following:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Display"/>
```

It seems you forgot to close the button tag, so AAPT could not generate a new R.class.

Answer (score 1):

Generally R.java is not created when you have errors on one or more xml files. In this case the error is in the Button tag (the IDE should warn you about that error).

Comment: oops sorry, i edited my button tag still not getting!

Comment: What IDE are you using? Is Eclipse? Can you post your xml files?

Comment: That file seems to be correct, try to perform a clean

Comment: My problem is resolved ..thanx by the way for reply .. +1 by me ;) for reply!!