# Cleaned project, my R.java file won't generate because of error in XML file?

Tags: java, android, xml, genymotion

I was trying to run my project in my Genymotion emulator, but none of the new updated buttons that I added were showing when I ran my Android application. So, I made a copy of my project to run a "clean" on it because I've had problems with my R.java file not being generated after cleaning it, and I was right as the R.java file didn't generate in the copied project. I'm almost sure it's a problem in my XML file, but my XML file shows no errors.

I also had the same error before, which I posted about here: [R cannot be resolved to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768370/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

The R file is not being generated so all my calls in MainActivity like `mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.crayon);` are stating "R cannot be resolved to a variable" which I know points to a problem in my XML file.

Here is my activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:gravity="center"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/greyorcolor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/grey"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/reyscale" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/color" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/smallorlarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/large" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/small" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

<edu.berkeley.cs160.opalkale.prog2.DrawingView
    android:id="@+id/drawing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

My strings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

   <string name="app_name">Drawing</string>
   <string name="greyscale">Greyscale</string>
   <string name="color">Color</string>
   <string name="small">Small Brush</string>
   <string name="large">Large Brush</string>
   <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string> </resources>
```

My MainActivity.java file:

```
package edu.berkeley.cs160.opalkale.prog2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Bitmap munBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.crayon);
    Bitmap mBitmap = munBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    DrawingView drawingView = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawing);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Problems window: 
[image]
    enter code here

Comment: may i knw edu.berkeley.cs160.opalkale.prog2.DrawingView is this correct located in package

Comment: in which line you are getting error ?

Comment: Does your string resource file end with a `</resources>` tag ? Also it can't block but take time to indent your layout file (in eclipse CTRL+A CTRL+I), the structure is not clear.

Comment: @DigveshPatel Yes because it was working when there was nothing in the xml file but the `<edu.berkeley.cs160.opalkale.prog2.DrawingView` part.

Comment: Don't copy a project when it doesn't work. Clean the logs, clean the errors in eclipse, then clean the project, *understand* the error, fix it and re-run.

Comment: @Snicolas yep, not sure why it wasn't showing up in the post (fixed it)

Comment: @user3301551 I'm not getting any errors. The R file is not being generated so all my calls like `mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.crayon);` are stating "R cannot be resolved to a variable" which I know points to a problem in my XML file.

Comment: @Opal: I've posted answer

Comment: @Opal still you have problem ?

Comment: @user3301551 yes, it is still a problem :(

Comment: try this, press `ctrl+shift+o` in your MainActivity and then clean and run the project.

Comment: @Opal can you show the details  what shows in problems section `Window -> Show View -> Problems`......?????????????

Comment: @Opal what is `line No. 35 in DrawingView.java file`..??

Comment: `mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.crayon);`

Comment: @Opal is that file is available in the drawable folder..??

Comment: @SilentKiller yes it is!

Comment: @Opal do one thing comment your custom class code in XML file then clean and build your project. then check still error remains or gone.?

Comment: @SilentKiller when I do that, now I have all the errors still except for "Error executing aapt"

Comment: @Opal all errors mean.? what others errors occurs.?

Comment: @SilentKiller All the same errors noted in the problems log picture posted above, except for the first one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47472/discussion-between-silentkiller-and-opal)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly clear about this, but are you using eclipse? If you are, I've had similar issues where R.java was not being generated, but eclipse was not flagging any errors. In all cases, there was actually errors in the XML layout files, but I to detect them I had to open the "Problems" view to find out what they are. If you don't have it open already, you could try that: `Window -> Show View -> Problems`

Comment: Yes I am, see here for my previous post, I added a picture of my "Problems" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768370/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable

Comment: I also just posted what I see in my problems log above!

Answer (score 0):

This happens since eclipse is not able to build the project. Try restarting eclipse and see if R file gets created. If not clean again now and see if it works.

Comment: See this similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating

Comment: It's not a problem with eclipse, the problem lies in my XML file for sure.

Comment: I've tried to restart, clean, etc many times and nothing is changing.

Answer (score 0):

You have one special character in radiobutton's name `@`

```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/grey"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@Greyscale" />                  // Here
```

You need to remove that `@`

Comment: OP has updated his question. He has fixed this "typo" but still the problem is not solved.

Comment: @Mehul That is an Invalid Edit. Don't do this again.

Comment: @MehulJoisar You must not add any content to existing post while editing.

Comment: @user3301551: I tried to improve your answer so that you can learn to answer.anyways,be happy with downvotes.I dont mind :-)

Comment: @MehulJoisar I appreciate your work but still it is invalid edit as per rule. And I dont care about downvotes if my answer is wrong.

Comment: @user3301551: No offence but kindly look at [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) . and you will find out the rule for 'Moderation Privilege' to make the posts better :-)

Comment: @MehulJoisar Opps You right. `to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
to add related resources or hyperlinks` is legal. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

That's happen many times to me, that's why I'm using Android studio,

Let's come to main Answer :)

Firstly, save your project Clean again, if still not generating your `R.java` file, then Restart again. may hope that would work :)

Here is my question when i posted it. :)

[Suddently, "R.java" was deleted from my "CheckBox" program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673421/suddently-r-java-was-deleted-from-my-checkbox-program)

Comment: I've tried to restart, clean, etc many times and nothing is changing. It's definitely a problem in my XML file

Answer (score 0):

there are two possibilities of the errror:

1:
you `forgot to add drawable` named "crayon" in drawable folder.

2:
`package error`: you just need to check the import statements.
it should look like

import com.test.example.R;

where your package name = com.test.example

Comment: crayon is a jpg in drawable (just double checked. where should I look for the import statement to see if it's there? In my custom views class or in my main activity?

Comment: @Opal: in your main activity

Comment: I updated to show my MainActivity.java file. It is not a problem of importing the R.java file if it is not being generated in the first place